# Set path variable and run command

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'm trying to do such task:

- Setup git in path environment
- Run bower

I want to do that as single command: 
`cmd.exe /c "set PATH=%PATH%;c:\git && bower.cmd"`

Unfortunately it doesn't work. For some reason the path variable doesn't change.

Does any body know why?

Comment: "In a batch file the default behaviour is to read and expand variables one line at a time, if you use & to run multiple commands on a single line, then any variable changes will not be visible until execution moves to the next line." from http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: You can either create a new batch file with the commands on separate lines, or set the path inside `bower.cmd`

Comment: @DavidPostill `In a batch file ... any variable changes will not be visible until execution moves to the next line` That's correct as far as %variable% expansion goes in the batch file itself. But the commands are still executed sequentially with immediate effect, so any subsequent command _will_  see the just updated variable. That's easiest to verify if testing with a non-pre-existent environment variable, for example `set "aaa=zzz" && set aaa` will display `aaa=zzz` at the prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead:

```
cmd.exe /c "set "PATH=%PATH%;c:\git" && bower.cmd"
```

The way it was written *without* the extra pair of quotes around `set "PATH=%PATH%;c:\git"`, what was appended to the `PATH` was `C:\git`+ a space at the end.

Comment: It looks like the space at the end was the issue